# Setting Z3 verbosity from the API

Tags: z3, smt

I'm wondering, is there a way to set verbosity in the Z3 API? Something equivalent to the `-v 10` option on the command line?

Answer (score 0):

When using the programmatic API, you get finer level control on what gets printed. See this function here: https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/group__capi.html#ga3c7d069930a7bec13f8c30cd795abc33

To figure out exactly which `tags` are allowed, you'll have to look through the source code. (And also compile z3 in the debug mode.)